# How To Listen To Items Clicks in Widgets Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, widget, android-widget

**The Problem**

I've implemented this code [AppWidgetListView](https://github.com/Nailik/AppWidgetListView/tree/master/AppWidgetListView) and I've tried to attach clicks.

What's going well: so, clicks from buttons from widget but outside the ListView, works. You can see the click result from that buttons on OnReceive method from a class (WordWidget) that implemented AppWidgetProvider.

what does not work: when you click an item (or an element from that item) from ListView, it doesn't show a thing.

**Attempts**:

Example 1

```
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WordWidget));

configIntent.PutExtra("appWidgetId", ids[i]);
PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button, configPendingIntent);
```

Example 2

```
Intent active = new Intent(context, typeof(WordWidget));
active.SetAction("aaa");
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button, actionPendingIntent);
```

Example 3

```
var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(WordWidget));
intent.SetAction(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate);
intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetIds, ids);

var piBackground = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button, piBackground);
```

Example 4

```
var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(WordWidget));
intent.SetAction("test");
remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button, PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0));
```

Example 5

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://google.com"));

remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button, intent);
```

---

I've tried to replace typeof(WordWidget) with typeof(MainActivity) and it does not work. and I've tried to put that codes on public RemoteViews GetViewAt(int position) from ListProvider where the item layout is built and it does not work.

Comment: and the solution from [link](https://www.javafixing.com/2022/02/fixed-how-to-attach-onclick-listener-to.html) does not work (setOnClickFillInIntent, setPendingIntentTemplate)

Answer (score 0):

As a test, I implemented the following function: When clicking on the ListView, enter the main page of the APP.

You can refer to the following code:

We need to call `SetOnClickFillInIntent` to differentiate the item on-click behavior.

In `ListProvider.cs`

```
    public RemoteViews GetViewAt(int position)
    {
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
         context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.list_row);
        ListItem listItem = listItemList[position];
        remoteView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.heading, listItem.heading);
        remoteView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.content, listItem.content);

       // add code here 
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.PutInt("position", position);
        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.PutExtras(extras);
        // Make it possible to distinguish the individual on-click
        // action of a given item
        remoteView.SetOnClickFillInIntent(Resource.Id.item_frame, fillInIntent);

        return remoteView;

    }
```

**Note:** Here `item_frame` is the id of root element of `list_row.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/item_frame"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
```

In `WidgetProvider.cs`

Here,we set the pending intent in `OnUpdate` method

```
    public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        int N = appWidgetIds.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetIds[i]);

            // we add code here
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
           // activityIntent.SetPackage(context.PackageName);
            // Set the action for the intent.
            // When the user touches a particular view.
            //activityIntent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetIds[i]);
            //activityIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(activityIntent.ToUri(Android.Content.IntentUriType.AndroidAppScheme)));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, appWidgetIds[i], activityIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            remoteViews.SetPendingIntentTemplate(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, pendingIntent);



            appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've already tried. Does not work. Even copy pasted. Maybe, the listening method is not good; I've tried OnNewIntent from MainActivity and on WidgetService and on OnReceive from AppWidgetProvider. But when you click nothing is happening. So... where, how do you listen for that event?

Comment: After adding the above code and clicking on the ListView, can't you get to the APP home page?

Comment: No, I can't. Not even in the debbug output console. Does not show anything even in the debug output console.